# How to update local storage value before unmounting React modal login component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

I want my home page to use the authorization token in local storage to fetch a signed-in user after a page refresh. Conditionally rendering the login modal and logout components unmounts the modal before the local storage is updated and causes the warning below. I tried setting _mount to true in componentDidMount and false in componentWillUnmount in the login modal component, but I still got the warning and unwanted effect.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Formik (created by WithFormik(ModalContainer))
    in WithFormik(ModalContainer) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Header.js:64)
    in a (created by MenuItem)
    in MenuItem (at Header.js:59)
```

Please see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-hooks-67l4k?file=/client/src/components/Header.js) to reproduce a similar warning.

Answer (score 0):

I did download your sandbox code locally and tried and I'm able to run the application smoothly. Steps followed were:

```
1. Exported as ZIP from provided sandbox link.
2. Ran yarn install  to install all the dependencies.
3. Ran yarn build
4. Ran yarn start
```

Comment: thanks for trying. I think the steps you followed are correct. I also got 502 error messages when I tried to login(credentials are in `server.js`).  Are you able to interact with the login modal?

Comment: Yes, I am able to interact with the login modal as well and able to see console logs while clicking on login link and when entering credentials on the login screen. After entering details it takes some time and the login dispatch event throws error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can check the attached screenshot wherein I able to login with the provided credentials on server file.]

The server file utilises the userDetails json to authenticate. 
Also the terminal shows the token for reference

Comment: Yes, I didn't say in my first post. The warning `React not updating the state on unmounted component` was the issue I was trying to solve. I understand the app is incomplete; I just wanted to recreate the warning to get some guidance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding about the problem and solution you can go through this link below
https://www.debuggr.io/react-update-unmounted-component/

Meanwhile, I am trying to fix the problem using a class component approach

Comment: Thanks, I'll go check out the link. The class component approach is perfect, as I am not very comfortable with using hooks with React Redux.